# how to load two records in single row?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

It is possible to load two records in a single row in tableview?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create your own UILabel elements within the UITableViewCell. You could either add the new UILabels to you cell, (I think there is a content view you should add them to, or you can subclass UITableViewCell and have it create the labels for you and provide access to them with labels.

Answer (score 1):

yss it is possible use descriptionlabel.text to show another labels as

```
cellobj.textLabel.text=[arr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cellobj.descriptionLabel.text=[arr2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: But i am getting complete data in one array only if we have two array we can do like this

Comment: You can use index no. pf array to save it like this  `cellobj.textLabel.text=[cobj1.grouplistarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Answer (score 1):

Use UITableViewCell with Subtitle style:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease]; } //did the subtitle style

        NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
        cell.textLabel.text = record1;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = record2;
    }
    return cell;
}
```